# How to list all projects added to a solution in Linux terminal?

Tags: .net, linux, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

In Ubuntu terminal I can add a project to a solution with the following:

```
dotnet sln add ./projectName/projectName.csproj
```

What command can I run in the terminal, to see all the projects that have been added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dotnet sln list`. If multiple solutions are present in folder - add solution name:

```
dotnet sln SolutionName.sln list
```

- [dotnet sln list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln#list)
- [dotnet list reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-reference) (for projects)